# Convert to hyperlink whenever enter filename in active cell google script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet named "Source" which contains the below columns:
filename on column A, its link on column B.

I would like to create a google script that whenever I insert filename into a cell of an active sheet, it will automatically convert that cell to a hyperlink by looking up the link from "Source" sheet).

I have tried searching from many forums, but I can't find one that fits my purpose. Any help, please.

Comment: Can you provide some example desired outputs for inputs that are found in column A,  A table of inputs and outputs would be nice

Comment: E.g. I have a sheet named 'Source' that A column contains 01.pdf, 02.pdf, 03.pdf, etc and B column has
 www.drive/folder/01.pdf, www.drive/folder/02.pdf, www.drive/folder/03.pdf, etc. I want to have a script that whenever I type filename, let's say '01.pdf' in a cell on another sheet, it will auto update this plain text to a hyperlink text. it's the same as we use formula =hyperlink("www.drive/folder/01.pdf", "01.pdf") which the link comes from column B and filename from column A in 'Source' sheet and if I type 03.pdf, it will be a hyperlink to file 03.pdf and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your e.value is one of the sheet names in column A of Source Sheet.  If it is then replace it with column B value

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.value) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    let lsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Source")
    let obj = lsh.getRange(2,1,lsh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues().reduce((a,r,i) => (a[r[0]]=r[1],a),{})
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(e.value)) {
      e.range.setValue(obj[e.value]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner. May I ask what "Entry" and "Gate1" are. I got an error Cannot read properties of undefined on line 2: e.source.toast("Entry");

Comment: They are debugging lines.  My guess is that you tried to run the function from the script editor without supplying the event object which is supplied from the onEdit trigger.  Unfortunately that cannot be done.  You must learn to debug these functions while performing the edits that you wish to capture based upon the conditional statements created by the author of the script.  You can supply and event object if you wish but it's much more complicated in my opinion,